# Mongodb (v2.4.0) $match aggregate not working with date range

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb java driver thru maven repository (as below in pom.xml) to query transactions between date range with aggregate framwork.  The java driver generates following $match that I tried to validate on mongo console and found that it does not work:

```
db.transactions.aggregate(
{ "$match" : 
    { 
        "created_at" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2001-04-12T12:00:00.000Z"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "2020-04-13T12:00:00.000Z"}}
    }
}
)
```

If I remove $date block and replace it with ISOdate function and date string then it seem to be working. I failed to understand why it does not work in java ($match JSON - I had fetched from eclipse to try in mongo console and that do not work as well.)

```
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

does any one know why $date is not working with aggregate using MongoDB v2.4.0?

Comment: Try the answer and let me know if it does not work.. and if it does not work please provide us the information on the data store in the Database. since I assumed that `date` is a embedded filed in `created_at` in your document.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. The code I had provided is been generated by MongoDB java driver therefore I don't see "" is an issue.
created_at  is date field and holds the ISO date formate. Please find JSON below for your reference:  


    {
      "created_at" : ISODate("2013-04-18T10:42:22Z"),
      "payment_token" : "f7e595ec-1cdd-4e5d-93c5-eca8e5f9f876"
    }

Comment: I have updated my answer with reference to the JSON you provided. Please try and let us know. Since the same code is working for me with MongoDB 2.2.3 I hope it works on your version as well with no issues.

Comment: nope, it does not work. I am using mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.4.0 (i.e. v2.4.0)

Comment: Sorry, based on the past conversions, I am not getting any clues to solve... But for sure the below provided code do work on my machine

Comment: On further analysis, it seems that issue is not with query but the way date is stored in DB. Ref# https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit/issues/50#issuecomment-13227827 and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-565?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel. However, per example in last link when I try to insert date in DB it inserts with ISODate insted of $date format. But println of serialize  do print required format i.e. with $date. Not sure why DB insert is not inserting as expected.

Comment: @Jaymin Were you able to find out the issue with date range query in aggregation? My research shows that if you use the query as part of find it works. When used in aggregation pipeline, it throws syntax erros.

Answer (score 4):

You have to format the date before passing onto $match aggregate.

```
Order.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            createdAt: {
              $gte: new Date(req.body.startDate),
              $lt: new Date(req.body.endDate)
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'acbinstallerpayments',
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: 'customerObjectID',
            as: 'installerPaymentDetails'
          }
        }
      ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this just worked. Creating a date object while sending the date works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I got it solved by removing the `""` & `$` prefix on the `$date` field of in `$match`.
For you remove the same for `$date`, `$gt` & `$lte`

So that it should look like

```
db.transactions.aggregate(
{ "$match" : 
         { 
          'created_at': { 
                         $gt: "2001-04-12T12:00:00.000Z", 
                         $lt: "2020-04-13T12:00:00.000Z"
                        }
         }
});
```

Comment: I'm using CFMongoDB (ColdFusion) with the Mongo java driver and this format worked.  I had to add quotes around `"$gt"` & `"$lt"`, but that may have just been a ColdFusion requirement. (NOTE: Valid JSON requires double quotes. Perhaps the java driver doesn't currently care, but it may in the future.)