# MongoDB date range query throws syntax errors when used in aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using Java Driver for MongoDB to query database. I am getting syntax errors when trying to execute range query on a date field in aggregation. It works fine if I use it as part of find query only. Aggregation is the problem here. I used the following Java query code :

```
new BasicDBObject("requestDate", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", fromDate).add("$lte", toDate).get());
```

requestDate is the field I want to query. I tried debugging the code and ran the generated query using command line and I still get syntax errors. Not sure whats wrong here.

Mongo Query generated by the code:

```
 { "requestDate" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2015-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-03-09T04:00:00.000Z"}}}
```

EDIT. Adding relevant Code:

```
BasicDBObject match = null;
if (organizationId != null) {
    match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("organizationId", organizationId));
}
if (optionalParams != null) {
    Date fromDate = (Date) optionalParams.get("fromDate");
    Date toDate = (Date) optionalParams.get("toDate");
    if (match == null) {
        match = new BasicDBObject("requestDate", new BasicDBObject("$gte", fromDate).append("$lte", toDate));
    } else {
        match.append("requestDate", new BasicDBObject("$gte", fromDate).append("$lte", toDate));
    }   
}
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", MongoDBUtil.getProjectDateFields());
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", MongoDBUtil.getGroupDateFields()).append("total", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
List<DBObject> pipeline;
if (match != null) {
    pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, project, group, sort);
} else {
    pipeline = Arrays.asList(project, group, sort);
}
```

Comment: Sure it is the query itself that is the problem? Replace $date with either new Date()-calls or ISODate("") if you are using the mongo shell.

Comment: @marko Yes query itself is the problem. I was able to replace $date with new Date() in command shell and it worked fine. What about java code. How can I make sure that the java code does that?

Comment: @marko I realized that code works fine if I use it as find query. When I use it in aggregation, the problem kicks in. Similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987601/mongodb-v2-4-0-match-aggregate-not-working-with-date-range

Comment: How are you actually using this within your aggregation pipeline? Moreover what is the error? The representation is just how the Java driver expresses the serialization and it is basically correct and more accurate to how the BSON serialization is represented to the server request. Please edit your question so we can see the aggregation context, where the error is likely caused because you are using it in the wrong way.

Comment: @Neil Lunn. You are absolutely right. I figured it out last night before I slept. I was confused with the representation and was trying to run the same query in command line. The issue was with the way I was using aggregation. $match was missing in my logic. I will edit the question with more code. If you can answer it, I will accept it. Or I can answer it too as I found the solution but you were first to make it public.

Comment: @NeilLunn To be specific, when line no 9 is executed, the match in pipiline is missing the $match. I was relying on the query generated by debugger console. How can someone know that java driver representation will not run in command line. Is there any documentation that I can refer to?

Comment: @vinay This should serve as an example of when presenting a problem you show your code related to the problem and the exact error message received.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sure. Lesson learnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief, you broke your [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage construction because like all pipeline directives that "key" is "mandatory. Your conditional building should not be checking is the existing state is `null` but rather "appending" to what you need to define at the top as a "empty" `$match`:

```
// BasicDBObject match = null; // wrong!
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject()); // correct!
if (organizationId != null) {
    match.append("organizationId", organizationId);
}
if (optionalParams != null) {
    Date fromDate = (Date) optionalParams.get("fromDate");
    Date toDate = (Date) optionalParams.get("toDate");
    match.append("requestDate", new BasicDBObject("$gte", fromDate)
        .append("$lte", toDate));
}
```

So then, without a value for `organizationId` you get a pipeline generated like so:

```
{ "$match": { 
    "requestDate" : { 
        "$gte" : { "$date" : "2015-03-01T05:00:00.000Z" },
        "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-03-09T04:00:00.000Z" }
    }
}
```

Without that `$match` key this is not a valid pipeline stage and it will error on submission to the aggregation pipeline.

There is nothing wrong with the generated syntax and all, full explanation is in the manual under [Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). The MongoShell uses "strict" mode as mentioned there so it requires it's own wrappers.

Comment: I get syntax errors when I run the query with $date. Its runs fine if I use new Date('2015-03-01T05:00:00.000Z') instead of { "$date" : "2015-03-01T05:00:00.000Z" }

Comment: $date not working in shell was misleading me all time.  $match was logical bug. Once I fixed the $match issue, my code runs fine. Its just that I cannot use $date when querying in shell .

Comment: Perhaps the initial content was a bit to glib. Just read the documentation link on Extended JSON provided that explains it.