# Mongo match in aggregate not working for date using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongoDB java driver to query transactions between date range with aggregate framework. I am trying to use following mongo query:

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
{ "$match":{
    "order_commit_time": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2015-04-30T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "$lte": ISODate("2016-08-23T19:53:23.000")
    }
}
},
{
"$unwind": "$discounts_list"
}, {
"$unwind": "$discounts_list.discount_split"
}, {
"$group" :{
    "_id": null,
    count:{$sum:1}
}
}]
);
```

The java code I am using to make query is following:

```java
Date startDate = new Date(period.getStartTime().getTimeInMillis());
Date endDate = new Date(period.getEndTime().getTimeInMillis());

BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject(mongoDateField, 
    new BasicDBObject("$gte", startDate).append("$lte", endDate)));
BasicDBObject discount_list = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$discounts_list");
BasicDBObject discount_split = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$discounts_list.discount_split");
BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", null)
    .append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1)));
AggregationOutput output = mongoCollection.getCollection().aggregate(match, discount_list, discount_split, group);
```

But this java query is returning empty result. However if I use the mongo query on console, it is working fine. Also if I remove match from aggregation, query works fine but don't filter the result according to date. Moreover the same "match" DBObject, when used in count or find as query, works fine like this:

```java
query = new BasicDBObject(mongoDateField, new BasicDBObject("$gte", startDate).append("$lte", endDate));
mongoCount = mongoCollection.getCollection().count(query);
```

Is there any way to convert the mongo query to java equivalent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to use a debugger to interrogate the BasicDBObject objects, to confirm whether they look right or not?

Comment: I have checked it, its fine. I have searched the web, there was issue like this but no solution.Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987601/mongodb-v2-4-0-match-aggregate-not-working-with-date-range#

Answer (score 1):

Just use "allowDiskUse(true)", as follow,

```
AggregationOutput output = mongoCollection.getCollection().aggregate(match, discount_list, discount_split, group).allowDiskUse(true);
```

Comment: please, consider to accept the answer if you got help. It will helpful other with the same kind of issue.

Comment: I reset my password just to login and vote this answer up! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject(mongoDateField, 
    new BasicDBObject("$gte", period.getStartTime().getTimeInMillis()).append("$lte", period.getEndTime().getTimeInMillis())));
```

I just released a new annotation based library that works like the Spring Data @Query annotation but for aggregation queries.  This will eliminate all the boiler plate code and allow you to execute aggregate queries just by declaring this annotation on the repository interface methods.  It also works with the date parameter as a long.